# Writing things in labels to the next line(JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, label, jlabel

I am using JLabels and I want to write something like this.
"A" after writing "A" goes to the next line and writes "B".After that writes a variable coming from a method

I can accomplish writing "A" and "B" like that with the following code

```
JLabel label105 = new JLabel();
    label105.setText("<html>Gas Company</html>");
```

But when I try to insert an integer value from system to set text I fail.Either it writes to the same line or it doesnt work at all.Can anyone write how can I use setText to accomplish this?

Basically what I want is the following in labels.

```
 System.out.print("A");
System.out.println("B");
System.out.println(getValue());
```

Comment: what do you mean with `if i try to insert an integer value`? and what exactly is `it doesn´t work at all`? is it an exception, doesn´t it do anything?

Comment: You should show the exact code that "doesn't work", and explain how it doesn't work, and what it should have displayed. It's hard to understand your "A" and "B" explanation, as the code you are showing doesn't do that at all, it just displays "Gas Company".

Comment: I tried but stack overflow didnt let me write what I want.I will edit the code in a different way now

Comment: Create and post a decent [mcve] for the best help. Else we still have no clue as to what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String string="<html>A<br />B<br />"+Integer.toString(intValue)+"</html>";

label105.setText(string);
```

The variable `intValue` is your integer value

Comment: This was the exact thing  I asked about and it works.I dont think the question is clueless..